# How to interleave arrays in julia

Tags: arrays, julia

Is it possible to interleave two arrays in julia?

For example if `a=[1:10]` and `b=[11:20]` I want to be able to return

```
20-element Array{Int64,1}:
  1
  11
  2
  12
  3
  13
  4
  14
  .
  .
  .
```

Somewhat similar to what ruby can do [Merge and interleave two arrays in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7312713/merge-and-interleave-two-arrays-in-ruby)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Figured it out!

```
reshape([a b]',20,1)
```

and for something more general:

```
reshape([a b].',size(a,1)+size(b,1),1)
```

we can use a hack to get vectors instead of 1D arrays:

```
reshape([a b].',size(a,1)+size(b,1),1)[:]
```

Comment: The difference may not be important for your use case, but those will produce `20x1 Array{Int64,2}` objects, not `10-element Array{Int64,1}` objects.

Comment: Ah yes thanks for pointing that out. I edited the answer using the hack specified here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23957734/getting-1d-subsets-of-multi-dimensional-arrays-in-julia

Answer (score 9):

There is a straightforward way to do this without needing to use the `reshape()` function. In particular, we can just bind the vectors into a matrix and then use `[:]` on the transpose of that matrix. For example:

```
    julia> a = 1:10
    julia> b = 11:20
    julia> [a b]'[:]
    20-element Array{Int64,1}:
     1
    11
     2
    12
     3
    13
     .
     .
     .
    20
```

Taking the transpose of the matrix `[a b]` gives us a 2-by-10 matrix, and then `[:]` returns all of its elements in the form of a vector. The reason `[:]` works so nicely for us is because Julia uses [column-major ordering](http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.4/manual/performance-tips/#access-arrays-in-memory-order-along-columns).

Comment: For tuple arrays this fails, but you can use `permutedims(tuples_2D)[:]` instead of `tuples_2D'[:]`

Answer (score 4):

You could just use

```
reshape([a b].', length(a)+length(b))
```

to get a vector.

Comment: thanks, noted. I guess the hack is more usefull when you are note explicitly using reshape.

Answer (score 2):

```
julia> @benchmark collect(Iterators.flatten(zip(a,b))) setup = begin a=rand(100); b=rand(100) end
BenchmarkTools.Trial: 10000 samples with 714 evaluations.
 Range (min … max):  190.895 ns …   1.548 μs  ┊ GC (min … max): 0.00% … 65.85%
 Time  (median):     238.843 ns               ┊ GC (median):    0.00%
 Time  (mean ± σ):   265.428 ns ± 148.757 ns  ┊ GC (mean ± σ):  8.40% ± 11.75%

  ▅▅██▅▃▂▂▁                                                  ▁▁ ▂
  ██████████▇█▇▇▅▄▄▃▁▁▁▃▄█▅▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▃▁▁▁▁▃▃▁▁▁▁▁▃▁▃▄▆▇███ █
  191 ns        Histogram: log(frequency) by time       1.11 μs <

 Memory estimate: 1.77 KiB, allocs estimate: 1.
```

it seems that

```
collect(Iterators.flatten(zip(a,b)))
```

is much faster

Answer (score 1):

For completeness, expanding @bdeonovic's solution to 2 dimensional arrays.

```
julia>  a
2×2 Array{Int64,2}:
 1  2
 3  4

julia> b
2×2 Array{Int64,2}:
 6  7
 8  9
```

---

Interweaving rows:

```
julia> reshape([a[:] b[:]]', 4, 2)
4×2 Array{Int64,2}:
 1  2
 6  7
 3  4
 8  9
```

Interweaving columns:

```
julia> reshape( [a' b']', 2, 4 )
2×4 Array{Int64,2}:
 1  6  2  7
 3  8  4  9
```

Interweaving arrays (stacking/vcatting):

```
julia> reshape([a' b']', 4, 2)
4×2 Array{Int64,2}:
 1  2
 3  4
 6  7
 8  9
```